# WPF Frame Content is null in unit test

Tags: c#, wpf

I have had success with some other unit tests around WPF Windows.  This one has got me.

I have an `xunit` test project in `dotnet core 5` that has a Window.  The test sets the content of a frame to a new page.  However the assertion to check the content is not null will not work as the ViewNavigator content is null.

This is using [Xunit.StaFact](https://github.com/AArnott/Xunit.StaFact) to allow running tests under STA thread.

#### Window

```
<Window x:Class="acme.foonav.FrameNavigationWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="FrameNavigationWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>
        <Frame x:Name="ViewNavigator"></Frame>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

#### Test

```
[UIFact]
public void Navigate_To_Pages()
{
    FrameNavigationWindow window = new();

    var monitor = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
    window.ViewNavigator.NavigationService.Navigated += (sender, args) => monitor.Set();
    window.ViewNavigator.ContentRendered += (sender, args) => monitor.Set();

    // set content here
    window.ViewNavigator.Content = new PageNoVm1();

    monitor.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    // content always null
    Assert.Equal(typeof(PageNoVm1), window.ViewNavigator.Content.GetType());
}
```

#### Page

Just an empty page.

```
<Page x:Class="acme.foonav.Pages.PageNoVm1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:acme.foonav.Pages"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Title="PageNoVm1" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>        
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I can't spot anything obviously wrong.

** Updates **

I have tried using different flavours of `window.Dispatcher.Invoke` to set the `Content`:

```
var monitor = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

window.ViewNavigator.NavigationService.Navigated += (sender, args) => monitor.Set();
window.ViewNavigator.ContentRendered += (sender, args) => monitor.Set();

var page = new PageNoVm1();
window.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => window.ViewNavigator.Content = page);
monitor.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like previous successes were to create window on separate thread and this is missing `System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()`

Comment: So this fails as well meaning the `Content` is never set?: `var page = new PageNoVm1(); window.ViewNavigator.Content = page; Assert.Equal(page, window.ViewNavigator.Content);`

Comment: window.ViewNavigator.Content is always null.  So the above still fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you synchronously blocking for 3 or 5 seconds? If WPF needs some time, you're not feeding it this way -- you're starving it.

Try changing the test method to be async, and then use *await* to give WPF time:

```
-monitor.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
+await Task.Delay(5000);
```

I don't know if this will solve the problem, but it's a better way to pause execution in general.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  It explains a lot.  Switching to that fixed the issue (although a small delay of 500 millis).

Comment: Great. In the interest of a stable and fast unit test, I recommend replacing the delay with a prioritized scheduled task. If you use `await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => {}, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);` for example, you'll resume as soon as all WPF data-binding is done. I suspect *some* priority level will get this working reliably and fast.